# SVG embedded in Jupyter notebook taking up more space than expected

Tags: svg, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to embed an SVG containing the following in a Markdown cell in my Jupyter notebook:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="102.55939mm"
   height="78.562569mm"
   viewBox="0 0 102.55939 78.562569"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto-start-reverse"
       markerWidth="4.0606599"
       markerHeight="6.7071066"
       viewBox="0 0 4.0606602 6.7071068"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:context-stroke;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt"
         d="M 3,-3 0,0 3,3"
         id="path5057"
         transform="rotate(180,0.125,0)" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-45.308179,-77.332021)">
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.6;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect347"
       height="60"
       x="87.567566"
       y="95.594589"
       width="60" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.586;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow1)"
       d="m 87.580724,125.60499 c 0,0 -25.67467,-13.96811 -25.67467,-13.96811"
       id="path966" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:4.23333px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';white-space:pre;inline-size:36.7738;display:inline;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.600001;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="43.783787"
       y="100.33784"
       id="text1241"
       transform="translate(1.5479905,4.60098)"><tspan
         x="43.783787"
         y="100.33784"
         id="tspan5722"><tspan
           style="stroke-width:0.6"
           id="tspan5720">Specified head  </tspan></tspan><tspan
         x="43.783787"
         y="105.6295"
         id="tspan5726"><tspan
           style="stroke-width:0.6"
           id="tspan5724">h1 in  layer 1</tspan></tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:4.23333px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';white-space:pre;inline-size:36.7738;display:inline;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.600001;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="43.783787"
       y="100.33784"
       id="text1241-1"
       transform="translate(42.455028,-19.489481)"><tspan
         x="43.783787"
         y="100.33784"
         id="tspan5730"><tspan
           style="stroke-width:0.6"
           id="tspan5728">Well located in </tspan></tspan><tspan
         x="43.783787"
         y="105.6295"
         id="tspan5734"><tspan
           style="stroke-width:0.6"
           id="tspan5732">layer 10</tspan></tspan></text>
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.600001;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:0.600001, 1.2;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 117.56757,95.594587 c 0,0 0,60.000003 0,60.000003"
       id="path1293" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.600001;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:0.600001, 1.2;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 87.567565,125.59459 c 0,0 59.999995,0 59.999995,0"
       id="path1305" />
    <circle
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.600001;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path2243"
       cx="102.6703"
       cy="111.3797"
       r="2.0067568" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.946176;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.586;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow1)"
       d="m 102.67029,111.58432 c 0,0 0,-22.961864 0,-22.961864"
       id="path2390" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'm not super familiar with all the implementation details of SVG, but I do know that I exported the sketch from Inkscape with the following settings:

[image]

So as far as I can tell, the "white space" around the actual figure is minimized, which is what I want.

Unfortunately when I try to embed this into a markdown cell in my jupyter notebook as follows:

```
![test](tutorial-1-bcs.svg)
```

There is a large amount of white space around the plot, which I do not want.

Is the markdown cell adding this extra white space, or is it the SVG? How can I reduce the white space to a minimum in the markdown cell?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that I was "Hiding export settings from inkscape". Deactivating this option resulted in a correctly sized SVG:

[image]